# Why do my Machine Strike sets keep getting reset?

Tags: horizon-forbidden-west

In Forbidden West there's a new in-game boardgame called **Machine Strike**, where you challenge other players and try to destroy their pieces on a tiled field.
I saved a couple of sets after I obtained more pieces, and it worked as expected. I defeated the 3 Beginner players without any problem and now the game doesn't save my sets. Everytime I start a match my sets are all empty.

Is there a reason for that? Is it just a bug because I have a certain number of sets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I deleted all my sets, creating a new one with the same machines I was using and it was correctly loaded last time I was challenged.
I don't know what happened, but my guess is that the game can't bear more than 2-3 sets. So I think it was just a bug.